# in excel 2010 I want to count both "Yes" and "N/A" and not count a "No"

Tags: excel

I am trying to count both "Yes" and/or "N/A" to populate a score.  The three options are Yes, No and N/A. Currently the cells are set-up in list format thought the Data Validation on Excel.  However, I can not get the cell to count either Yes and N/A. When i put in this formula:

```
=Countsif (B:B, "Yes", B:B, "N/A)
```

I get a zero, even though 3 of my cells are either a "Yes" or an "N/A". What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Do a sum of countif -

`=sum(countif(B:B,"yes"),countif(B:B,"N/A"))`

a `countifs` tries to match criteria with **AND** not **OR** - [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Can sum up the counts

```
=COUNTIF(B:B,"yes") + COUNTIF(B:B,"n/a")
```